# Is it bad in terms of memory usage if I use static fields in activities and fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, static, fragment

I was wondering whether I should declare my fields static or not inside activities/fragments.

At first I thought I'd make everything static, since every fragment/activity would only have only one instance in memory at a time (is this correct?)

Then I read here at SO that fields marked as static would never be GC'ed, since only only objects (along with their instance variables) are garbage collected. I'm puzzled

Here's how I'm doing it now....

```
public class Container extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {


private static ViewPager sPager;
private static ActionBar sActionBar;
private static PagerAdapter sAdapter;
private static DrawerLayout sDrawerLayout;
private static ListView sDrawerList;
private static ActionBarDrawerToggle sDrawerToggle; 

//more code...
```

(I'm sorry if i'm mixing things up here, I'm new to programming...Also English isn't my first language)

Any answers are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
What is the impact of Static variable ?
```

Static variables serve as "roots" to the GC. Therefore, unless you explicitly set them to null, they will live as long as the program lives, and so is everything reachable from them.

So, if you declare a view as static what happens is, the reference created to the activity or fragment stays alive even after the activity is destroyed (may be due to change in device orientation) which creates a memory leak.

```
So should we never use Static ?
```

**`Answer is NO. YOU SHOULD USE STATIC CAUTIOUSLY`**

If a variable or data is intended to be there for as long as the program is running, then it is most definitely not a leak, it is more likely a "**permanent singleton**". If the OS tries to access a data and if the object is null, it is a bigger issue. So in those case, static is helpful.

```
If needed, How to handle the static variable ?
```

Any variable or view you declare as static, should be assigned null in the activity `onDestroy` Method or any other appropriate method.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The objects in your example are a bunch of views and an adapter. Views and adapters have a lifecycle that's tied to the activity that they're part of – if the activity is gone, then the views that it's made up of should also be gone.

Therefore, these objects should **not** be held in `static` fields (unless you null those fields in `onDestroy()`, but really, why bother).

Answer (score 0):

You have a **class** Container, if you make these fields static, it means these are fields of the **class** and common for all objects/instances of this class.
You are right, for Activities you will probably only have one instance, but still these fields belong to this one instance, as Barend said in his response, and are not common with others.
Also your point with garbage collection is valid and an important point on mobile devices since resources are limited and memory leaks happen easily when static is not used carefully.

`static`: Use it if a field is shared between instances of the class and may even exist without any instance existing. If you are unsure, better don't use static.

Comment: Thanks for answering!

You just explained what the static modifier do, which I kind of knew   already. My question was more about it causing leaks ; )

Comment: You have already explained the possible leak :)   
Your activity may be gone already, but the static variables will remain in memory, because they are not associated with the gone instance, but with the class itself instead. If you do this for every activity that the user visits (even very shortly), all these data will fill up the RAM.

Comment: On a different note, aren't static methods faster? Most my methods are static because of this, and I'd get "non static field X cannot be referenced from a static context" if I were to remove the static modifier from my fields